# Using ErrorDocument Directive with <directory>

Tags: directory

I have a website which has three different directories. I want to create a custom error page for each of the different directories. What i did is as follows:

```
<Directory "directory1">
    ErrorDocument 404 /directory1/error.php
</Directory>

<Directory "directory2">
    ErrorDocument 404 /directory2/error.php
</Directory>

<Directory "directory3">
    ErrorDocument 404 /directory3/error.php
</Directory>
```

Now, when I am using this code in my root level htaccess, internal server is the result which i am getting. Need help to sort the issue.

Comment: It's possible that the PHP file is causing the `Internal Server Error`.  The file that is run when a 404 is encountered causes a 500 error instead.  Have you tried the above with just a string instead of a PHP file? `"Not found in directory1"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`<directory>` directive [cannot be used](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) in an htaccess file.

Instead you could:

- Create an htaccess file in each of the subfolders with just the `ErrorDocument` directive
- Write some hairy mod_rewrite rules
- *Let PHP do the work.*

  **/.htaccess**

  ```
  ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php
  ```

  **/errors.php**

  ```
  <?php
  $error_include = sprintf('%s/%s/error.php', __DIR__,
      explode('/', pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_DIRNAME))[1]);

  if (@file_exists($error_include)) {
      include($error_include);
  } else {
      echo 'Not Found: and no error document!';
  }
  ```

Comment: i tried  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 and it worked for me. Simple.

Comment: For anyone reading this later.  `<IfModule...` does not "fix" the overall problem.